# Python vs SQL outer joins give different results. Why?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, outer-join

I am having some trouble understanding the difference between Python (Pandas) FULL OUTER JOINS and Microsoft SQL Server. Without going into the data, maybe somebody understands the theory of how they function differently.
I am running both codes in parallel to make sure its working while I am learning Python.

SQL Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM df1 a
        FULL OUTER JOIN df2 b
        on a.id_no=b.idno
    ) abc
FULL OUTER JOIN df3 c
on abc.id_no=c.idno
```

Python Code:

```
TripleMerge = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id_no', right_on=df2['idno'].astype(np.int64), how='outer').merge(
        df3, left_on='id_no', right_on=df3['idno'].astype(np.int64), how='outer')
```

The first part of each join gives me the same number of rows (2323)
The second part results in a total of 4951 rows for SQL and 4552 for Python. I can't figure it out.

**Some clues:**
Python would not let me join on 'idno' without converting int64.
I sorted all dfs in SQL and Python in the same way to control for ordering.

If you can think of any places to investigate, please let me know. Or if you know how to better write the Python code (or a different way altogether to test the row output, please let me know).

Thanks!

Comment: update: Python was the 'correct' one. The SQL code would have been more appropriate as creating a list of distinct IDno's and doing 3 left joins. Python was automatically doing it this way by creating an index out of the IDno's or somethign like that

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to the abc selection in your python example. Pretty sure your syntax is just a little off there.

In SQL Server you're saying make this join then join that to another table on a value.

Try this:

pd.merge(pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='id_no', right_on='idno', how='outer'),df3,left_on='id_no', right_on='idno',how='outer')

Comment: Thanks for the suggested cleanup. Unfortunately, this gave me the exact same code as before. the SQL version still contains 399 extra rows.